# JQuery pass this to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, hover, this

I need to send `this` to the capIn() and capOut() functions so that I can target the children divs of the correct .slide. How do I pass `this` to a function. `this` would be what is hovered.

```
$(".slide").hover(function(){capIn();capOut();});
```

Comment: Is that your actual code? Are you doing nothing but calling those functions? Do you really want them both called for the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at the function names `capIn` and `capOut` it makes sense that they are 2 different behaviors. I believe you have 2 different behaviors on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. `hover` method can take 2 methods, one for `mouseenter` and another for `mouseleave`. You can try this

```
$(".slide").hover(capIn, capOut);
```

You can use `this` inside `capIn` and `capOut` it will point to `.slide` element which you hovered on.

```
function capIn(){
   var $childrens = $(this).children();
}

function capOut(){
   var $childrens = $(this).children();
}
```

Comment: This may be what's wanted, but it isn't identical to the code in the question.

Comment: I believe this is the ultimate requirement of OP.

Comment: Note that your code doesn't do the same thing as the OP's code. The OP is calling both functions on both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. Your code is calling `capIn` on `mouseenter`, and `capOut` on `mouseleave`. Now, from the names of the OP's functions, that may be what they actually want, but I'd still highlight it.

Comment: Looking at the function names `capIn` and `capOut` it makes sense that they are 2 different behaviors. May be OP doesn't know `hover` takes 2 different handlers for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Comment: Yeah, that would be my bet too, but I agree with @T.J.Crowder that it would be good to note it in the answer.

Comment: This is what I was trying to achieve. This works but how do I target a specific class instead of all children. Ex: `var $childrens = $(this).SOMECLASS;`

Comment: You can pass the class name inside `children()` as selector.

Comment: @JonathanEckman - Thats kool I could read your mind and provide you the right solution :)

Comment: Got everything to work but have .slideDown is sliding up. Started a new [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231172/jquery-slidedown-is-sliding-up) if you're interested.

Answer (score 10):

```
$(".slide").hover(function(){
    capIn.apply(this);
    capOut.apply(this);
});
```

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

**UPDATE:**

If `capIn` is for `mouseenter` and `capOut` is for `mouseleave`, then:

```
$(".slide").hover(function(){
    capIn.apply(this);
}, function(){
    capOut.apply(this);
});
```

`ShankarSangoli`'s solution is more succinct, but if any arguments need to be passed in addition to `this`, then: `capIn.apply(this, arguments)` can be used.

Comment: This shouldn't get a -1. It correctly replicates the code in the question, but set the `this` value in the functions. Only thing I'd add would be to send the `arguments` along just in case the `event` or any custom args are needed.

Comment: In the second example, there's no need for `...hover(function() { capIn.apply(this); }, function() { capOut.apply(this); })`, just `...hover(capIn, capOut)`. In the first example, picking up on @amnotiam's point, it would be `capIn.apply(this, arguments);`.

Comment: `.hover(capIn.apply(this), capOut.apply(this))` won't work. `fn.apply(...)` is a function call so you need to wrap it in an anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function capOut(jq) {
    alert(jq.hasClass('slide'))
}

$(".slide").hover(function () {
    capIn(this),
    capOut($(this)) //to pass a jQuery object wrapping 'this'
});
```