# JQuery .slideDown() is sliding up

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, slidedown, slideup

This works but I'm not sure why. In `function capIn()`, in my mind the line `$botcap.slideDown("slow")` should slide the div down. It slides it up. If I try using `.slideUp()` nothing happens as if it is trying to slide it down. Can anyone explain this to me?

```
$(".slide").hover(capIn, capOut);

function capIn(){
    //slide top caption down
    var $topcap = $(this).children(".topcap");
    $topcap.slideDown("slow");

    //slide bottom caption up
    //!! Why does slideDown slide caption up here?
    var $botcap = $(this).children(".botcap");
    $botcap.slideDown("slow")
}

function capOut(){
    //slide top back up
    var $topcap = $(this).children(".topcap");
    $topcap.slideUp("slow");

    //slide bottom back down
    var $botcap = $(this).children(".botcap");
    $botcap.slideUp("slow");
}
```

Comment: can you post the markup or better if you can make a demo on http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle - your description is hard to visualise.

Comment: Need more markup as to whats going on in HTML and CSS.  Hard to tell just based on this javascript whats going wrong

Comment: fiddle isn't giving me a unique url. Saves as jsfiddle.net/#save. Are they still down for maintenance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery's `slideDown` and `slideUp` functions are actually misnomers. As the documentation for `slideUp` puts it:

> Hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.

The hiding is achieved by modifying the height of the element; normally, this means that the lower edge of the element appears to slide up, hence the name. However, if the element is anchored at the bottom (e.g. by setting `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0`), the height modification will make the top edge appear to slide down.

Answer (score 0):

One possible fix would be to wrap `$('.botcap')` elements with a container and align the container to the bottom.

Comment: You'd have to be sure your container's height was set to the full visible height of `.botcap`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of positioning the element with absolute position and bottom: 0; This will actually treat the element as if it is bottom-based, therefore its slideDown() is going upwards. It can be fixed by using top: (height of element) instead of bottom: 0.